# Code PrimePi (writing out the function)

Tags: prime-numbers

I would like to write a function that outputs the built in function PrimePi, which gives the number of primes π(x) less than or equal to x. So far, I have:

```
enter[n_] := Count[[2, n], Prime]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Edits to my code: myPrime = {};
en[n_] := For[i = 1, i < n, i ++,
  AppendTo[myPrime, Prime[i]];]
Print[Length[myPrime]]

Comment: Your code contains the three markings of a beginner: `For`, `AppendTo`, and `Print`. More proper *Mathematica* code would be something like `enter[n_Integer?Positive] := Range[n] // PrimeQ // Boole // Total`. Please have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) and [the most common pitfalls awaiting new users](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393).

Comment: If you want to do this without using `PrimeQ` you could start by implementing the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) and then count the number of integers left over.

Comment: It looks like you are just guessing at the syntax instead of looking it up in the documentation. There is nothing wrong with trying to guess, but please do not stop there. Before you ask a question, look it up in the documentation. `[2,n]` is invalid syntax, the second argument of `Count` must be a pattern, etc. Go through these, look up `Count` in the docs, and ask about the specific problem where you got stuck (e.g. not sure how to write a correct pattern).

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest working variation of your code is

```
enter[n_] := Count[Range[2, n], _?PrimeQ]
```

The function `Count` takes a pattern (look it up in the help).  In this case, I'm matching anything that `PrimeQ` recognises as a prime.

Comment: That works. I've also got another code I've just written that avoiding Prime Q. Even though I use Prime, I'm trying to avoid the built in functions as much as possible.